# Extract all parameters from a Spring controller

Tags: spring-boot

Given a Spring controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test/{date}")
public String details(
        @PathVariable LocalDate date,
        @RequestParam(required = false) SortOptions sort,
        Model model) {...}
```

I would like to get a Map with all the parameter: {'date': date, "sort": sort}

```
Map<String, Object> map = getCallingParameters(); // <----
```

I would like a general solution, not for this particular controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
@GetMapping("/test/{date}")
public String details(
        @RequestBody Map<String,Object> body) {...}
```

Note, that if you change your idea you can also use @RequsetBody with wrapper objects (which I suggest to consider).

Comment: I cannot change the controllers. I need this functionality as a side activity and I was hopping there is a simple way to get all parameters. To me, this doesn't sound like a ridiculous request and I am suprised that Spring does not provide such feature.

Comment: I can get RequestParam with request.getParameterNames() but I cannot get a list of PathVariable,